# How to use Babel Plugin Proposal Throw Expressions in Codesandbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, codesandbox

Using React in Codesandbox i tried to throw new Error('Something went wrong'); and i had this error:

[image]

I already added this dependency: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-throw-expressions and still won't work.

**Here's my code**

```
<div className="App">
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <h1>Counter {counter >= 10 ? throw new Error("Over 10!") : null}</h1>
  </ErrorBoundary>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding a dependency in your sandbox you must enable it. To add a Babel dependency add a `.babelrc` config file. Then add the plugin name into the plugins array.

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "proposal-optional-chaining",
    "proposal-throw-expressions"
  ],
}
```

[image]

The configuration files can be added from the config button on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem on hand, I tried do add the "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions", "@babel/plugin-syntax-throw-expressions" to babelrc.json and tried babel.config.json to and somewhat react-scripts ignore these files.

I fixed this by editing node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js, and switching the babelrc and config fields to true.

```
{
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'),
                    {
                      runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? 'automatic' : 'classic',
                    },
                  ],
                ],
                // @remove-on-eject-begin
                babelrc: true,
                configFile: true,
                // Make sure we have a unique cache identifier, erring on the
                // side of caution.
                // We remove this when the user ejects because the default
                // is sane and uses Babel options. Instead of options, we use
                // the react-scripts and babel-preset-react-app versions.
```